# JQuery.tablesorter is sorting twice the same column from the same table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I got 2 tables "newsTable" and "eventsTable". I want to make them sortable with jquery.sortable plugin, its working pretty ok but when i click on any column its sorting twice, so in fact im getting the starting position :/ How to solve the problem? Why columns are being sorted twice? I had no problem with that when I had only one table in page, now I have 2 and problems have came :(

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#newsTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#newsTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager1")}); 
}); 

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#eventsTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#eventsTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager2")}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Is possible post your table html as well? Maybe u are using the  same class in both tables.

Comment: <table class="table" id="newsTable"> and <table class="table" id="eventsTable">

Comment: im using the same class because thery are both tables so how can i not ?

Comment: It's ok because your trigger are in the ID not in the Class. I'm doing some tests here to find out if i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the tablesorter four times for both tables, hence the sorting occurs four times.

Try calling `$(document).ready()` only once:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#newsTable").tablesorter( 
    {
        widthFixed: true, 
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        sortList: [[1,0]]
    }).tablesorterPager(
    {
        container: $("#pager1"),
        size: 5
    }); 

    $("#eventsTable").tablesorter( 
    {
        widthFixed: true, 
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        sortList: [[1,0]]
    }).tablesorterPager(
    {
        container: $("#pager2"),
        size: 5
    }); 
});
```

Comment: but there is one problem still, to both tables I got pager (pager1 and pager2) they are working good if i set 10/20/30 rows per page, but on starting the page i setted that only 5 should be shown, but it shows much more :/ it looks like it showing all rows on beginning not looking into how much i setted in code to starts with

Comment: I've updated the answer to show only 5 rows initially. Do keep in mind that if you have a large table with lots of rows, it can take quite a while for the tablesorter (and pager) to have rendered it, showing initally much more rows.